# cordova/ cordova-plugin-keyboard and react js. How right install and call methods of plugin in react js

Tags: cordova, reactjs, cordova-plugins

I use cordova and react js. I want to use cordova-plugin-keyboard. I install it and try to call methods but see only error. How right install and call methods of plugin in react js.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve 'cordova-plugin-keyboard' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\dkfsh\myapp\src\src\components\Persons'

but i check it is there

Comment: How are you building and running the app?

Comment: for create build npm run build and for run app npm start. I use https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESlint need to write that Keyboard is global variable 
 `/*global Keyboard*/`